# Fastest Iterated Method for Game Logic: thread, idle handler, winproc, or something I don't know?

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance

I'm creating a new windows C# form app which uses various hardware systems (Kinect V2 and a 3D RFID localization system). This is a scientific app, not a game, but will have logic that is definitely game-like (need to collect and manage physics data for 3d env objects, render graphical 3D environments, etc). In most native Windows environment games you might have a basic main loop which calls logic updates and rendering functions while listening for DirectInput from the mse and kbd.  But since this is c#, and it's more of an event driven environment I believe I need to rely upon one of 3 options:

(1) creating a new thread and using that as a main loop for logic updates and 3d rendering (listening for escape logic of course), or
(2) creating an application idle handler function that checks if the app is idle and then processes the logic, or 
(3) over-riding winproc and doing my game-like logic there.

So I created a test app: it has a clock display and uses all three of the methods just mentioned to independently calculate an FPS counter for each method.  This measures how often each method gets iterated per second, and is displayed next to the clock once a second.

But the result is not what I expected. I thought the new thread would be the fastest method, akin to a main loop. But it's not. WinProc is getting called the most (even when setting priority of the thread to highest). Also, the application idle handler is the slowest (as expected, it's only called on idle!) - but I have read that idle handling is the canonical way to do window C# form game type app. All three use the exact same logic to calculate their FPS (just an int that gets a ++ each time their method gets called).

Here are the results of the app after it's run for a few seconds and stabilized:

Thread Based FPS:3,200
Application Idle Handler FPS:600
WinProc Override FPS:10,000

I know why the idle handler is the slowest.  But why are threads iterated less often than winproc?  What am I missing there? Also, when interacting with the form window, winproc sees a big increase in iterations per second (as expected), but so does the thread!  Why would an independent thread get called more often just because the GUI is interacted with?  I am clearly not understanding something fundamental here - could someone clue me in?

**UPDATE 1:** This is an edit since my first version of the question got put on hold - apparently folks wanted to see some actual code!  This isn't an "i don't know why my codes doesn't work" - I am trying to tease out performance...all of it works.  So here is the basic code - hopefully this will help!

Thank you!

CODE: The ClockText variables are just 3 text boxes which are updated with a timestamp in each method, while the UPS variables are the text boxes updated with the calculated FPS from each method:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //for DllImport of c++ functionality for win msg processing

namespace Clock1
{
    public partial class ClockForm : Form
    {
        //General app variables
        System.Threading.Thread t;
        bool KeepLooping = true;
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime StopTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan TimePassed = new TimeSpan();
        int FrameTick1 = 0;
        int FrameTick2 = 0;
        int FrameTick3 = 0;

        //Imported for use of c++ win msg variables

            //For message handler version
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct NativeMessage
            {
                public IntPtr Handle;
                public uint Message;
                public IntPtr WParameter;
                public IntPtr LParameter;
                public uint Time;
                public Point Location;
            }
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int PeekMessage(out NativeMessage message, IntPtr window, uint filterMin, uint filterMax, uint remove);

            //Imported for winproc loop version processing on WM_PAINT (0x000F) messages (lowest allocation overhead)
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int SendNotifyMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);  

        //Primary form loop
        public ClockForm()
        {
            //Loaded on program start

            //Init components for C# environment
            InitializeComponent();

            //For winproc method, override painting (double check the functionality of this):
            //SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

            //Multithreaded method initialization:
            t = new System.Threading.Thread(MainLoop);
            t.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Highest;
            t.Start();

            //Application idle event handling allocation:
            Application.Idle += HandleApplicationIdle;
        }

       //Multithreading method primary func
        public void MainLoop()
        {
            while (KeepLooping == true)
            {
                //Count Frames
                FrameTick1++;

                //Use Invoke because the new thread can't access UI elements directly
                MethodInvoker MI = delegate() 
                {
                    //Update time:
                    ClockText.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt");
                };
               ClockText.Invoke(MI);              
            }

            //When KeepLooping is no longer true, exit:
            Application.Exit();
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        //Application idle event handling method primary func
        void HandleApplicationIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (IsApplicationIdle())
            {
                //Count Frames
                FrameTick2++;

                //Call frame update:
                UpdatesPerSecond();

                //Update time text
                ClockText2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt");
            }
        }

        //Application idle event handling method secondary func
        bool IsApplicationIdle()
        {
            NativeMessage result;
            return PeekMessage(out result, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)0, (uint)0, (uint)0) == 0;
        }

        //Winproc method (override for the WndProc handler):
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            //Updates with full FPS capacity (may be a CPU hit though, so consider doing this only on a certain event - maybe not WM_PAINT, but something else, a faster more regular heartbeat
            //NOte: All messages are sent to the WndProc method after getting filtered through the PreProcessMessage method.  Recursive infinite loop risk when working with windows control variables, due to updates and such

            //Count Frames
            FrameTick3++;

            //Update clock text:
            ClockText3.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt");

            //Proceed with regular message handling
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        private void UpdatesPerSecond()
        {
            //Time Calc:
            StopTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimePassed = StopTime - StartTime;                                              
            if (TimePassed.Seconds >= 1)
            {
                //Update UPS/FPS count displays:
                UPS1.Text = FrameTick1.ToString("D");
                UPS2.Text = FrameTick2.ToString("D");
                UPS3.Text = FrameTick3.ToString("D");

                //Reset UPS count:
                FrameTick1 = 0;
                FrameTick2 = 0;
                FrameTick3 = 0;
                StartTime = DateTime.Now;
                TimePassed = TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
        }

        //Event handeler for exit button        
        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Detach event handler for idle event processing
            Application.Idle -= HandleApplicationIdle;

            //Stop the multi-threaded method
            KeepLooping = false;            
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**  I thought I would add update this after taking the advice of Zer0 below (which was spot on!) in case it might help someone else someday.  As he mentioned, the Invoke methods for GUI updates which were embedded in each processing method were causing the bottlenecks and strange results.  Much better results!!!

I relocated all the GUI updates to a timer function, and the results off the app look like this:

[image]

And the final code, in case anyone else wants to test for themselves is here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; //for DllImport of c++ functionality for win msg processing
using System.Globalization;

namespace Clock1
{
    public partial class VosClockForm : Form
    {
        //Timer for GUI updates:
        System.Windows.Forms.Timer MainTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

        //General app variables
        System.Threading.Thread t;
        bool KeepLooping = true;
        bool ExitApplicationNow = false;
        DateTime StartTime = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime StopTime = DateTime.Now;
        TimeSpan TimePassed = new TimeSpan();
        CultureInfo StrictCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        long MethodTick1 = 0;
        long MethodTick2 = 0;
        long MethodTick3 = 0;
        long FrameTick = 0;

        //Imported for use of c++ win msg variables

            //For message handler version
            [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
            public struct NativeMessage
            {
                public IntPtr Handle;
                public uint Message;
                public IntPtr WParameter;
                public IntPtr LParameter;
                public uint Time;
                public Point Location;
            }
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int PeekMessage(out NativeMessage message, IntPtr window, uint filterMin, uint filterMax, uint remove);

            //Imported for winproc loop version processing
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int SendNotifyMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);  

        //Primary form loop
        public ClockForm()
        {
            //Loaded on program start

            //Init components for C# environment
            InitializeComponent();

            //If overriding winproc based painting, need to tell system we are doing the drawing
            //SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);

            //Multithreaded method initialization:
            t = new System.Threading.Thread(MainLoop);
            t.Priority = System.Threading.ThreadPriority.Normal;
            t.Start();

            //Application idle event handling allocation:
            Application.Idle += HandleApplicationIdle;

            //Start the MainTimer for updates:
            MainTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MainTimerEvent);
            MainTimer.Interval = 15; //15 ms = 67 fps max, may need to tweak this a bit!
            MainTimer.Start();
        }

        //Multithreading method primary func (don't post GUI updates using Invoke here as it causes a huge bottleneck, holding up the mainloop to wait for a graphics update
        public void MainLoop()
        {
            while (KeepLooping == true)
            {
                //Count Frames
                MethodTick1++;
            }

            //When KeepLooping is no longer true, exit:
            ExitApplicationNow = true;
        }

        //Application idle event handling method primary func
        void HandleApplicationIdle(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            while (IsApplicationIdle())
            {
                //Count Frames
                MethodTick2++;
            }
        }

        //Application idle event handling method secondary func
        bool IsApplicationIdle()
        {
            NativeMessage result;
            return PeekMessage(out result, IntPtr.Zero, (uint)0, (uint)0, (uint)0) == 0;
        }

        //Winproc method (override for the WndProc handler): All messages are sent to the WndProc method after getting filtered through the PreProcessMessage method.  Recursive infinite loop risk when working with windows control variables, due to updates and such
        //Do NOT update any GUI elements in this function!
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            //Count Frames
            MethodTick3++;

            //Check for application exit (consider moving this to whatever function ends up handling periodic GUI updates and such)
            if (ExitApplicationNow == true)
            {
                //Detach event handler for idle event processing
                Application.Idle -= HandleApplicationIdle;

                //Exit:
                Application.Exit();
                Environment.Exit(1);
            } 

            //Proceed with regular message handling
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }

        private void UpdateInterface() 
        {
            //Update Clock:
            lblClock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff tt");

            //GUI Update tick:
            FrameTick++;

            //UPS Calc:
            StopTime = DateTime.Now;
            TimePassed = StopTime - StartTime;                                              
            if (TimePassed.Seconds >= 1)
            {
                //Update GUI FPS
                lblGuiFps.Text = FrameTick.ToString("###,###,###,###", StrictCulture);

                //Update UPS/FPS count displays:
                lblUPS1.Text = MethodTick1.ToString("###,###,###,###", StrictCulture);
                lblUPS2.Text = MethodTick2.ToString("###,###,###,###", StrictCulture);
                lblUPS3.Text = MethodTick3.ToString("###,###,###,###", StrictCulture);

                //Reset UPS count:
                MethodTick1 = 0;
                MethodTick2 = 0;
                MethodTick3 = 0;
                FrameTick = 0;
                StartTime = DateTime.Now;
                TimePassed = TimeSpan.Zero;
            }
        }

        //Event handeler for exit button        
        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            //Stop the multi-threaded method
            KeepLooping = false;            
        }

        //Timer Event Handling: GUI Updates and related updates that don't require more than 60fps
        private void MainTimerEvent(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
        {
            //Call frame update
            UpdateInterface();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `But since this is c#, and it's more of an event driven environment I believe I need to rely upon one of 3 options` - says who? The basic game loop is literally just a `while` loop. There's no reason you couldn't do the same thing in C#.

Comment: Threaded: Don't update the UI thread so often. Usually the background thread that models your system can run at a high FPS, but there is no need to update the UI more than 30 to 60 FPS.  Read up on what the human eye can detect. This project is somewhat rudimentary and there are probably better thread management techniques, but the basic architecture of this very old C# app is the background thread queues updates to a data structure that the UI thread can grab from, freeing the background thread to run faster: https://github.com/AaronLS/CellularAutomataAsNeuralNetwork

Comment: @ChrisHayes: You are totally right of course, but with an app which also uses the Windows forms for other GUI user interactions you need to have event handling (a while loop without that would just lock out the windows form functionality unless threaded). That is what led into message handling and winproc. I'll have a rendering window with a 3d environment and multiple camera views as well as several typical window's GUI elements (data input forms and other interaction events) - kind of like a 3d modeling program or CAD program, less like a fullscreen game. Or am I over thinking this?

Comment: @AaronLS: Regarding refresh rate on the GUI, that was my plan for the actual app, and totally agree. I will definitely look at the link too, thanks!

Comment: Your WndProc version shouldn't have fallen from 10k/s to 280/s... any idea what you did to make that happen?

Comment: @BenVoigt `WndProc` fell because he removed `ClockText.Invoke(MI)`.  This uses the message queue, which `WndProc` processes.  This is a good thing.

Comment: @Zer0: Oh, now I understand.  It slowed down because the three tests are being run concurrently and fighting for resources.  Not usually the recommended way to conduct benchmarking.

Comment: @BenVoigt I did it all wrong at the beginning - you are right about that! But that's why I wrote a test app to figure it out - I knew that I either didn't know a few things I really should or was not thinking it through all the way ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest of those three methods will be a stand-alone `Thread`.

There's a fundamental flaw with your separate thread benchmark.  And it's `ClockText.Invoke(MI)`.  The reason being is `Invoke` is *blocking* until the GUI update is finished.  This is extremely slow.

If you don't want to block you can use `BeginInvoke` instead, but I wouldn't recommend that either.

When it comes to high performance I would strongly avoid "pushing" to the GUI thread (via `Invoke`, `BeginInvoke`, `SynchronizationContext`, etc...).  These all operate the same way- they use the Windows message queue like your `WndProc` solution is doing.  And you can flood that queue.  This is the same queue that responds to user input and a myriad of other things like paint messages.

Instead I'd recommend "pulling" from the GUI thread.  There are a ton of different ways to do this so I can't write you something specific without knowing more.  But a simple way is to use a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` and refresh the GUI every so often.

Comment: Ah! Yes, that appears to have been it all along - when I relocated all of the invoking out of those methods and into a timer based event threading came out on top (fastest).  I hadn't made the mental connection between the GUI updates and the painting events, and that it would block the thread that way! It makes total sense now.  Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: Added update to original post (update 2) to provide the final code and final results...  Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Zer0 is correct about why the thread ran slowly, of course.  But just because your thread now runs fast doesn't make it a good choice.  All those UI updates you are no longer paying for... can't be removed from a real game.

I would instead suggest using the new C# `async` keyword to run code continuously on the main UI thread.  You can update UI directly, and share variables with event handlers with no synchronization needed, because they run sequentially on the single thread.  The `async` keyword defaults to using a UI-compatible context when you use it on a UI thread, so that the game loop iterations effective go into the normal message queue, so queue processing takes place as normal.

All you need is to put your loop body in an `async` method, which you call once from `OnLoad`.  The last step in that method should be to `await` a call to itself, which is sort of a message-driven version of a tail call... the current invocation queues itself to be called again, and then returns to the message loop.

In older versions of C#, before `async` support was added, you could use `BeginInvoke` *from the UI thread* to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: That's a good point, and a great recommendation - thanks!  What I might end up doing is using async for triggering the GUI updates on a faster frequency than System.Windows.Forms.Timer will allow, but using a separate thread for real time data tracking and calculations (the scientific data we are collecting needs to be stored faster and with more demands than generating a smooth GUI render).  So 60-100 FPS for GUI ops, but 0.5 ms level interactions for scientific data usage/streaming.  Great food for thought - thank you again!